# Open a view (another xib) on button click in ipad application without navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

There is a image icon on the view on clicking on the icon another view(other xib) just opens up like the keyboard opens up and it should cover the screen only 30% from the bottom,having five icons on clicking any icon the current icon should be replaced with the selected icon.it is a ipad apps.thanks to all.

Comment: The view should open like the keyboard comes up over the view.

Comment: Use presentModel.presentModel can open like a keyboard.

Comment: thanks for the responce ,sorry for the incomplete question, actually what i have to do is on click of the image another view should appear which is smaller in size containing five images,  on clicking on any image the current image is replaced by the selected image in ipad application.

Comment: Edit your question first or should i edit it??

Comment: i have changed my ques  dear......

Comment: tell me one thing i.e. to show all of these icons u r using UIImageView or UIButton??

Comment: ok now i get ur question wait for a while i'm posting answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:-
In ViewDidLoad give frame size of youranotherviewcontroller likewise so that it covers only 30% Of the screen.after that :-

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 

    CGPoint startLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if([touch view]==yourFirstImageIcon)
    {
        // alloc this youranotherviewcontroller in ViewDidLoad
        [self presentModalViewController:youranotherviewcontroller animated:Yes];
        //It will show your another View having five more icons like keyboard
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [self.view addSubview:youranotherviewcontroller.view];
```

or

```
[self presentModalViewController:youranotherviewcontroller animated:NO];
```

I like to suggest you to read following apple guideline for the same. It may help you more.

[About View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Hope, this will help you

Comment: You should change your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewController *viewController=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
viewController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;//any type you want use that
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

I think this line of code is helpful for you just try and tell me hows this looks in your apps.

Comment: if I am wrong to follow the question then please explain me once.thank you

Comment: then why you are using another xib just use hidden view in that class only that is more easier for you.

Comment: while selecting another icon from the opened view the first view must be appear.

Comment: @aloksinha do one this use one static view and make it hidden and use that and add icon on that I think that good instant of call another view.

Comment: Your welcome please if my information i helpful for you make it right and increase my reputation.Thank you.

Comment: last day i don't have the required reputaion to vote up your answer.Today i get the reputations and now i m voting you up......many thanks for the responce.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use modal view approach that will give you slide up effect, or you can add sib view with animation, you can check with this -

```
UIView *myAnimationView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
myAnimationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:myAnimationView];

[myAnimationView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];
[myAnimationView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[myAnimationView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```